# Using advices to flatten a single subfolder

Tags: advice, navigation, ranger

One of Github's features i like is that it "flattens" path if a folder contains only one subfolder, i.e you have a `src` folder which has only `main` folder, so by clicking on `src` you go to the content of `main`. I'm using [ranger](https://github.com/ralesi/ranger.el) for navigation and want to achieve the same behaviour. I've decided to try advices for the first time, but can't get it working:

```
(defadvice ranger-find-file (before flatten-subfolder (entity ignore-history))
    (interactive "DInitialDirectory: ")
    (message "Calling ADVICE")
    (let ((folder (or entity (dired-get-filename nil t))))
      (when (and folder (file-directory-p folder))
        (let* ((subfolder (f-directories folder))
               (nr-of-subfolders (length subfolder)))
          (if (eq nr-of-subfolders 1)
              (flatten-subfolder (car subfolder))
            entity)))))
```

My understanding was that when i call [ranger-find-file](https://github.com/ralesi/ranger.el/blob/master/ranger.el#L1240), which has the following signature:

```
(defun ranger-find-file (&optional entry ignore-history) ...)
```

would first invoke my advice (`flatten-subfolder`) which would flatten (go down the path) folders and invoke `ranger-find-file` with the result of the advice above. Obviously it doesn't work, is there any way to do this?

Comment: (1) Are you aware that you are trying to use the old advise system? (2) Sanity check: did you call `ad-activate` with appropriate arguments? (otherwise advise won't have any effect).

Comment: @wvxvw i'm not and did not, hard to find articles on the advices, look further, thank you

Comment: This is the new advise system: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html